# How to connect my Android emulator to my local web server

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost

I've set up a web server on my own computer using xampp and I am trying to access the server in my App like this:

```
package com.example.connect2php;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
static String yahooStackInfo = "http://localhost/21/test03.php";

static String stockSymbol = "";
static String stockDaysLow = "";
static String stockDaysHigh = "";
static String stockChange = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... parms) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                new BasicHttpParams());

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(yahooStackInfo);

        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        String result = null;

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

            }

            result = theStringBuilder.toString();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        finally {

            try {

                if (inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();

            }

            catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        JSONObject jsonObject;

        try {

            result = result.substring(7);
            result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 2);

            // Log.v("JSONParser RESULT " , result);

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONObject queryJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");

            JSONObject resultsJSONObject = queryJSONObject
                    .getJSONObject("results");

            JSONObject quoteJSONObject = resultsJSONObject
                    .getJSONObject("quote");

            stockSymbol = quoteJSONObject.getString("symbol");
            stockSymbol = quoteJSONObject.getString("DaysLow");
            stockSymbol = quoteJSONObject.getString("DaysHigh");
            stockSymbol = quoteJSONObject.getString("Change");

        }

        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        TextView line1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line1);
        TextView line2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line2);
        TextView line3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line3);

        line1.setText("Stack: " + stockSymbol + " : " + stockChange);
        line2.setText("Days Low " + stockDaysLow);
        line3.setText("Days High " + stockDaysHigh);

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

But it didn't work. The server code is just:

```
echo 'cbfunc({"query":{"count":1,"created":"2013-08-24T13:38:58Z","lang":"en-US","results":    {"quote":{"symbol":"MSFT","AverageDailyVolume":"47950000","Change":"+2.36","DaysLow":"34.00","DaysHigh":"35.20","YearLow":"26.26","YearHigh":"36.43","MarketCapitalization":"289.5B","LastTradePriceOnly":"34.75","DaysRange":"34.00 - 35.20","Name":"Microsoft Corpora","Symbol":"MSFT","Volume":"225493744","StockExchange":"NasdaqNM"}}}})';
```

Here is the ip detail:

```
@ppeterka 
Microsoft Windows [版本 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\hcleeab>ipconfig / all

錯誤: 無法辨識或不完整的命令列。

使用方式:
    ipconfig [/allcompartments] [/? | /all |
                             /renew [adapter] | /release [adapter] |
                             /renew6 [adapter] | /release6 [adapter] |
                             /flushdns | /displaydns | /registerdns |
                             /showclassid adapter |
                             /setclassid adapter [classid] |
                             /showclassid6 adapter |
                             /setclassid6 adapter [classid] ]
```

其中
    adapter             連線名稱
                       (允許使用萬用字元 * 與 ?，請見範例)

```
選項:
   /?               顯示此說明訊息。
   /all             顯示完整設定資訊。
   /release         釋放指定介面卡的 IPv4 位址。
   /release6        釋放指定介面卡的 IPv6 位址。
   /renew           更新指定介面卡的 IPv4 位址。
   /renew6          更新指定介面卡的 IPv6 位址。
   /flushdns        清除 DNS 解析快取。
   /registerdns     重新整理所有 DHCP 租用並重新登錄 DNS 名稱。
   /displaydns      顯示 DNS 解析快取的內容。
   /showclassid     顯示介面卡所有允許的 DHCP 類別識別碼。
   /setclassid      修改 DHCP 類別識別碼。
   /showclassid6    顯示介面卡允許的所有 IPv6 DHCP 類別識別碼。
   /setclassid6     修改 IPv6 DHCP 類別識別碼。
```

預設是僅顯示每個繫結到 TCP/IP 之介面卡的 IP 位址、子網路遮罩及預設閘道。

對於 Release 與 Renew，如果沒有指定介面卡名稱，則會釋放或更新所有繫結到
TCP/IP 介面卡的 IP 位址租用。

對於 Setclassid 與 Setclassid6，如果沒有指定 ClassId，則將移除 ClassId。

範例:

> ipconfig                       ... 顯示資訊
>   ipconfig /all                  ... 顯示詳細資訊
>   ipconfig /renew                ... 更新所有介面卡
>   ipconfig /renew EL*            ... 更新所有名稱開頭為 EL 的連線
>   ipconfig /release *Con*        ... 釋放所有符合的連線，
>                                            例如 "Local Area Connection 1" 或
>                                                 "Local Area Connection 2"
>   ipconfig /allcompartments      ... 顯示所有區間的相關資訊
>   ipconfig /allcompartments /all ... 顯示所有區間的詳細資訊

C:\Users\hcleeab>ipconfig

Windows IP 設定

無線區域網路介面卡 無線網路連線:

媒體狀態 . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 媒體已中斷連線
   連線特定 DNS 尾碼 . . . . . . . . : hgcbroadband.com

通道介面卡 isatap.hgcbroadband.com:

```
媒體狀態 . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 媒體已中斷連線
連線特定 DNS 尾碼 . . . . . . . . : hgcbroadband.com

通道介面卡 6TO4 Adapter:


通道介面卡 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:


預設閘道 . . . . . . . . . . . . .:

C:\Users\hcleeab>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you could have added a logcat, this is most likely why your app fails to obtain the content:

```
static String yahooStackInfo = "http://localhost/21/test03.php";
```

This tells your android device to try and access itself. Localhost is the device itself. substitute that with the hostname or IP address of your host.

You might need to check firewall settings too...

**Update**

Updated with the IP in the comment:

```
static String yahooStackInfo = "http://223.18.60.177/21/test03.php";
```

Comment: sorry, I am still quite confusing. Can you explain more on 
why android couldn't connect to the server like this 
static String yahooStackInfo = "http://localhost/21/test03.php";

Comment: localhost is a loopback address. It always points on the same device where the code is executed. Read "Connect to yourself". When you run this code on Android it tries to connect to a server on the android device. But on your android device there is no server. Use your LAN IP. Make sure your firewall on PC enables incoming port 80 connections.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: for example if my lan IP is 223.18.60.177
should I just type this static String yahooStackInfo = "223.18.60.177";  but I want to connect to this file 
test03.php in my computer, not just the ip address.

Comment: It can be multiple things. This depends on a lot of network settings, for example firewall. If you just type the `http://223.18.60.177/21/test03.php` address into the browser of the phone, does the browser display the string from the PHP? If yes, there is a problem in the Android code somewhere. If the browser does not return the data, the error is on the server side.

Also, download logcat, and see what error you see in that. when running the app

Comment: does the browser display the string from the PHP?

NO.

Comment: @海志 李 Hmm, if zou enter the same thing into the computer's browser, is the data displayed? Does it work with localhost instead of the IP?

Comment: @ppeterka

http://localhost/21/test03.php  is ok but not 
http://223.18.60.177/21/test03.php

Comment: This means the server is OK, responds to requests, servers content. On Windows, in a command line, please run `ipconfig /all`, or if on Linux, please run `ifconfig`, and paste the results in the question please. Also, check if Windows firewall or IPTables (whichever applicable) is not in the way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

`http://10.0.2.2/21/test03.php`

10.0.2.2 is the special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

See:  [Emulator Network Address Space](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) in the official docs

Comment: sad to say. but it's still not working yet.

I've check the firewall on xampp control panel

Comment: I am using wifi to connect to the internet.

Comment: just a second.

it works finally and it is amazing. 
Thank you all of you guys. it helps a lot.

Although it shows nothing when I type http://10.0.2.2/21/test03.php
in the browser.
But it works in android 

a little bit wired but very helpful.